# TextView ImageView ConstraintLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Estou criando um app no android studio 2.3.3, mas ao colocar uma imagem utilizando o ImageView e um TextView ele apresentou o seguinte  this view is not constrained.view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
tools:context="com.example.tulio.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView //this view is not constrained.view

    android:id="@+id/txtNome1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:text="Alan Turing"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alan Mathison Turing OBE (23 de junho de 1912 — 7 de junho 
    de 1954) foi um matemático, lógico, criptoanalista e cientista da 
    computação britânico. Foi influente no desenvolvimento da ciência da 
     computação e na formalização do conceito de algoritmo e computação com 
    a máquina de Turing, desempenhando um papel importante na criação do 
    computador moderno.[1][2][3] Foi também pioneiro na inteligência 
     artificial e na ciência da computação.[4] É conhecido como o pai da 
     computação.  Durante a Segunda Guerra Mundial, Turing trabalhou para a 
     inteligência britânica em Bletchley Park, num centro especializado em 
      quebra de códigos. Por um tempo ele foi chefe do Hut 8, a seção 
     responsável pela criptoanálise da frota naval alemã. Planejou uma série 
     de técnicas para quebrar os códigos alemães, incluindo o método da 
     bomba eletromecânica, uma máquina eletromecânica que poderia encontrar 
     definições para a máquina Enigma."
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="297dp" />

<ImageView //this view is not constrained.view

    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alan"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="106dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />(Color.parseColor("#BABABA")); />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Num `ConstraintLayout` as views precisam estar "ancoradas" umas às outras e no seu caso não estão.

A forma mais fácil de fazer isso é pelo editor visual do Android Studio onde você seleciona uma view, arrasta um ponto (cima, baixo, esquerda, direita) de uma view até o ponto onde você quer "ancorar" na outra view ou em alguma margem da tela. Quando fizer isso, ele vai desenhar "setas" indicando a "ancoragem" e criar atributos como esses no XML das suas views:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_qualquer"
```

Aqui tem um ótimo tutorial sobre ConstraintLayout: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: obrigado man funcionou aqui com sua ajuda vlw